# How could add multi ${} in axios options's url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

I'm trying use react this UI to access CRUD api.

In the delete api will get which id(data id) want delete.

So the request url will like this

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/order/delete/{id}
```

I use axios to request HTTP

```
const headersList = {
    "auth-token": cookie.load('authToken'),
}

let reqOptions = {
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ! + event._id}`,
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: headersList,
}
    
axios.request(reqOptions).then((res) => {
    let { message, status } = res.data;
    
    if (message !== 'delete' || !status)
        return;
})
```

There are some error in reqOptions's url.

Couldn't get id when I click delete button on UI.

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/order/get62dd60aa8a23e8750556db9e 404 (Not Found)
```

(get62dd60aa8a23e8750556db9e was not the id on database)

I think the problem is how could compose process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ and event._id.

Have already try these compose

```
url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ! + event._id,
url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ}` + `${event._id}`,
```

Dose anybody have any idea?

Comment: What's the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ`? It's just a string; any string concatenation mechanism works. You sure you're not just forgetting to add the `/`? And possibly using the wrong env var since it'd be odd to use anything called `READ` to perform a `DELETE`?

Comment: You need to add the values of these variables to your question, and the URL you're expecting it to build, but it sounds like you need something like `url: \`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_READ}/{event._id}\``.

Comment: Hi , guy's, thanks for helping . I refer @root suggests and finally could use this `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_DELETE ! }/${event _id}` success send delete request. Regarding @Dave Newton  questions, REACT_APP_API_READ was a typo error the correct is REACT_APP_API_DELETE.